# Spritekit bounce effect from spritenode dragged by finger

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a demo app for testing physics in SpriteKit. I was able to simulate inertia after throwing sprite with pan gesture. When I release finger bouncing works great.
Problem is: **How to simulate bouncing during dragging?** I would like to red SKSpriteNode bounce off when I hit it with dragging SKSpriteNode.

I tried to set `self.selectedNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true` but then sprite moves away under finger even when I set correct position.

Here is my [repo](https://bitbucket.org/sirljan/bobo). Feel free to copy or experiment.

Crucial code:

```
func handlePan(panGestureRecognizer recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchLocationView = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
    let touchLocationScene = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocationView)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.showMoved = false
        let canditateNode = self.touchedNode(touchLocationScene)
        if let name = canditateNode.name, name.contains(kMovableNode) {
            self.selectedNode = canditateNode
            self.selectedNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false;
        }
    case .changed:
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view)
        if let position = self.selectedNode?.position {
            self.selectedNode?.position = CGPoint(x: position.x + translation.x, y: position.y - translation.y)
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)
        }
    case .ended:
        self.selectedNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true;
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: recognizer.view)
        self.selectedNode?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: velocity.x, dy: -velocity.y))
        self.selectedNode = nil
        self.showMoved = true
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

[image: Can't bounce while dragging, but can bounce after dragging.]

Comment: Tweak the bounciness of a physics body using its restitution property

Comment: As you can see bounciness is alright when I throw red sprite onto green. That's because I release finger before bounce. When I bounce with green sprite to red, it doesn't bounce even tough it has same restitution. I think it is because of `isDynamic` property is false during dragging.

Comment: Static bodies are not supposed to move at the first place... Does it behave correctly if you change both bodies to be dynamic ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. When you set position (according to touch position) it is not applied when there is collision with other sprite.